# Const array of closures taking a mutable reference to a struct with lifetime parameter in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have the following scenario in a Rust project:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    stuff: &'a i32,
}
```

thus I'm telling the compiler that my `Foo` struct holds a reference to something and I have to give it a lifetime to make that work, fine.

Now, I declare this:

```rust
type FooFunc<'a> = &'a dyn Fn(&'a mut Foo<'a>) -> bool;

const funcs: [FooFunc; 4] = [
    &|f| { *f.stuff = 0; false },
    &|f| { *f.stuff = 1; true },
    &|f| { *f.stuff = 2; true },
    &|f| { *f.stuff = 3; true },
];
```

and try to call a closure from that const array inside a "method" of `Foo`:

```rust
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn bar(&mut self, i: usize) -> bool {
        funcs[i](self)
    }
}
```

Reasoning about lifetimes, this should be fine since the `self` reference to the `Foo` struct has a lifetime `'a` (which sure thing doesn't outlive `'static`, that is the lifetime of the closures) so the closures should be able to receive `self` as a parameter without any issue.

And the borrow checker sort of agrees with this, but still reports an error I don't understand:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |         funcs[i](self)
  |                  ^^^^ lifetime mismatch
  |
  = note: expected type `&'static mut Foo<'static>`
             found type `&'static mut Foo<'a>`
note: the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 5:6...
 --> src/main.rs:5:6
  |
5 | impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
  |      ^^
  = note: ...does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime

error[E0312]: lifetime of reference outlives lifetime of borrowed content...
 --> src/main.rs:7:18
  |
7 |         funcs[i](self)
  |                  ^^^^
  |
  = note: ...the reference is valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 6:5
 --> src/main.rs:6:5
  |
6 | /     fn bar(&mut self, i: usize) -> bool {
7 | |         funcs[i](self)
8 | |     }
  | |_____^
```

It's telling me (in the `note` tags) that `the lifetime 'a as defined on the impl at 5:6 does not necessarily outlive the static lifetime` and that `the reference is valid for the static lifetime but the borrowed content is only valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the method body at 6:5`. While a compiler giving these kind of error messages is amazing, I still don't get what the problem is.

Talking about the second `note` (which is the one that sort of (tries to) explain the issue), I can't understand if the borrowed content is meant to be the const array or the self reference, but in either case:

- if the "borrowed content" is the const array, why would that be a problem even if an anonymous lifetime that matches the function body has been assigned to it? The closure just has to operate on the reference that gets passed as a parameter and return by transferring ownership of the return value, and not by returning a reference with some weird lifetime that could cause problems.
- if the "borrowed content" is the self reference, again, why would that be the problem? Okay, the self reference is no more `'a`, but it's another one (let's call it `'b`) which is "included" in `'a`, thus shouldn't outlive `'static`, right?

Sure thing I'm missing something here, any help would be appreciated.

**Note**: all the code in this post is just a stripped down version of the "architecture" I'm trying to implement - of course the logic you see in the example code could be easily implemented in a way simple manner, but that's not what I need. I would like to have a table of operations to do on my struct (thus the idea to make the elements closures that accept a `&mut` reference) and run these operations from a "method" of my struct. The actual type in the actual project is instead `[Option<[FooFunc<'a>; 6]>; 256]`, so we're talking a pretty big bi-dimensional "table", which I imagine would become quite unpleasant to implement with `match` statements, especially considering I reuse `FooFunc`s very often.

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=17034fe41c74d65d7a296ae812f19945

Comment: Does https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5450d6172eae9d58d85a3867a18d63be help?

Comment: It does indeed help, thank you very much. I didn't think about using `_` to phase out the lifetime in the type and that the lifetime associated to the type itself might have been the problem. I guess the lesson to learn is to try working with as few lifetimes specifiers as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `type FooFunc<'a> = &'a dyn Fn(&'a mut Foo<'a>) -> bool;` does **not** say "A `FooFunc` is a reference of any lifetime to a closure which takes a reference of any lifetime (to a `Foo` of the same lifetime)". Instead it says "A `FooFunc<'a>` is a reference with a *specific* lifetime `'a` to a closure which takes a reference of that *specific* lifetime `'a` (to a `Foo` of the same specific lifetime `'a`), *which is the same every time that closure is called*."

Moreover, when you omit the lifetime in the item declaration (`[FooFunc; 4]`) it's inferred to be `'static`. (This is because types themselves can't outlive their type parameters, but the item must be `'static`, so the only valid lifetime parameter is also `'static`.) So `funcs` is an array of references to closures which only accept `&'static mut Foo<'static>`.

What you probably want is `type FooFunc<'r> = &'r for<'a, 'b> dyn Fn(&'a mut Foo<'b>) -> bool;`, although this still fails due to mutability issues elsewhere. What that says is "A `FooFunc<'r>` is a reference of lifetime `'r` to a closure which accepts references of *any* lifetime to `Foo`s with *any* lifetime (the latter lifetime implicitly outlives the first lifetime)." `'r` will still be inferred as `'static` but that's okay because that's what you have.

Comment: Fixing the `mut` issue yields https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8678f6450d2c93316ba4d486dd5ee5e8 which compiles.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. In a comment under my question @ry also proposed this https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5450d6172eae9d58d85a3867a18d63be which declares the type as `type FooFunc = dyn Fn(&mut Foo<'_>) -> bool;`. I guess in this case the Rust compiler is just inferring lifetimes that, in the code you provided, are instead explicitly given?

Comment: Well the type you wrote is not a reference, so it's entirely different. But, basically, yes; I used all explicit lifetime annotations declared with `for<>`. I'm not entirely sure how many of them can be elided TBH because I don't yet remember how `'_` interacts with other entirely-elided lifetimes (are they inferred distinct or the same?). It's better to be explicit if you're not sure.